# Is it possible to create a require.js module that decides for itself when it is done loading?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

In a "normal" require.js function module, the module is considered "loaded" as soon as the module function returns:

```
define(function() {
    // As soon as this function returns, the module is "loaded"
});
```

But I have a module that needs to do some asynchronous script loading (specifically including some Google Javascript API-s) and I don't want my module to be considered "loaded" until I say it is.

When creating a loader plugin for require.js, you are supplied with an "onload" function that you can call when the plugin is done loading. This would be perfect for my case, but I don't want my Google API wrapper to be a plugin, I want it to appear to be a "normal" module. Plugins are treated differently by the optimizer and I don't want that headache. Also plugins must be required using special syntax, and I'd like to avoid having to remember that every time I use it.

I have combed through the [API](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html) several times without finding a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do. Is there an undocumented (or poorly documented) method of defining a module, where the module itself gets to decide when it should be considered "loaded"?

---

As an example, an implementation like this would be awesome, if it existed:

```
define(["onload"], function(onload) {
    setTimeout(onload, 5000);
});
```

The first time this module was required, it should take 5 seconds to "load".

Comment: May I ask you if you found a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

We bootstrap a lot of stuff using the convention below which is based on early releases (0.3.x) of the [MEAN](https://github.com/linnovate/mean) stack and uses the awesome [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library.

Using your example, it might look something like this:

```
// bootstrap.js

// Array of tasks to pass to async to execute.
var tasks = [];

// Require path
var thePath = __dirname + '/directoryContainingRequires';

// Build array of tasks to be executed in parallel.
fs.readdirSync(thePath).forEach(function (file) {
  if (~file.indexOf('.js')) {
    var filePath = thePath + '/' + file;

    tasks.push(function(callback) {
      require(filePath)(callback);
    });
  }
});

// Execute parallel methods.
async.parallel(
  tasks, 
  function(err) {
      if(err) console.error(err);
      console.log('All modules loaded!');
      process.exit(0);
  }
);
```

The file being required looks similar to this:

```
// yourModule.js
module.exports = function(moduleCallback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
     console.log('5 seconds elapsed');
     moduleCallback(null);
  }, 5000);
};
```

Comment: Yes, I could just use callbacks or promise objects (which would involve much more code every time the module is used), but the reason I asked this question was so that I could *avoid* that

Comment: Not necessarily more code.  You write the ugly bits (the loader/bootstrapper) once and then all the modules are pretty simple.  It looks like you're trying to force node to be something it's not. In general you never want to block on the main thread.

Comment: If I wanted to block, this wouldn't be a problem. As I said in the question, I want to do asynchronous stuff, and then notify require.js when the module is ready.